# Problems with hosting on github Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, github, hosting

I wrote a site using Angular. On my local hosting it was working great. When I hosted my site on `GitHub` I got 2 errors.

Link on my site: https://karpovich0.github.io/Magnise/

Screnshot with errros  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNW31.png

Comment: Can you add what you did to host the site on Github to your question?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8hrJ4oN1u_8 -  I hosted my site by this instruction

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `<base href="/Magnise/" />` to the `index.html` file.
It should set the base url which you have on github.